# How to shorten the url when using pagination and filtering with multiple checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, pagination, url-shortener

I am using `PagedList` for server side paging, and also have a textbox in the view for filtering the data, along with checkboxes to determine which fields in my model to filter based on the search text.

My current code is

View model

```
public class SearchPagingViewModels
{
    public IPagedList<AllResolution> Resolutions { get; set; }
    public string Keyword { get; set; } // serach text
    public bool IsResYearChecked { get; set; } // used to filter the ResolutionYear field
    public bool IsResNumChecked { get; set; } // used to filter the ResolutionNumber field
    public bool IsResTextChecked { get; set; } // used to filter the ResolutionText field
}
```

Controller

```
public ViewResult Index(int? page string keyword, bool? isResYearChecked, bool? isResNumChecked, bool? isResTextChecked)
{
    int pageSize = 25;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    bool searchYear = isResYearChecked.GetValueOrDefault();
    ....
    IQueryable<> resolutions = db.AllResolutions;
    if (searchKeyword != null)
    {
        if (searchYear)
        {
            resolutions = resolutions.Where(x => x.ResolutionYear.Contains(searchKeyword));
        }
        ....
    }
    resolutions = resolutions.OrderBy(c => c.ResolutionYear).ThenBy(c => c.ResolutionNumber);
    SearchPagingViewModels model = new SearchPagingViewModels
    {
        Keyword = keyword,
        IsResYearChecked = searchYear,
        ....
        Resolutions = resolutions.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model SearchPagingViewModels
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Resolutions", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Keyword)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Keyword)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsResYearChecked)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsResYearChecked)

    // .. ditto for IsResNumChecked etc

    <input type="submit" value="search" />
}

<table>
    <thead>
        ....
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var task in Model.Resolutions)
        {
            // .... build table rows
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Resolutions, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, Keyword = Model.Keyword, IsResYearChecked = Model.IsResYearChecked, IsResNumChecked = IsResNumChecked IsResTextChecked = Model.IsResTextChecked }))
```

While this works, the issue is that the for generates a long and ugly query string, for example

`.../Index?Keyword=someText&IsResYearChecked=true&IsResYearChecked=false&IsResNumChecked=false&IsResTextChecked=true&IsResTextChecked=false`

And now I want to add additional `bool` properties for filtering the records making it even worse and potentially exceeding the query string limit.

Is there a way to shorten the URL? Would this be related to routing? Would a new ViewModel be in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your could replace all your `bool` properties with an `enum` marked with the `[Flags]` attribute where each value in the `enum` represents a property in your model to search.

```
[Flags]
public enum FilterProperties
{
    None = 0,
    ResolutionYear = 1,
    ResolutionNumber = 2,
    ResolutionText = 4,
    .... // more properties
}
```

and the view model will be

```
public class SearchPagingViewModels
{
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public FilterProperties Filter { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<AllResolution> Resolutions { get; set; }
}
```

The controller method then becomes

```
public ViewResult Index(int? page string keyword, FilterProperties filter = FilterProperties.None)
{
    IQueryable<AllResolution> resolutions = db.AllResolutions;
    if (searchKeyword != null)
    {
        if (filter.HasFlag(FilterProperties.ResolutionYear)
        {
            resolutions = resolutions.Where(x => x.ResolutionYear.Contains(feyword));
        }
        // .... more if blocks for other enum values
    }
    resolutions = resolutions.OrderBy(c => c.ResolutionYear).ThenBy(c => c.ResolutionNumber);
    SearchPagingViewModels model = new SearchPagingViewModels
    {
        Keyword = keyword,
        Filter = filter,
        Resolutions = resolutions.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

You view will then be

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Resolutions", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Keyword)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Keyword)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Keyword)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Filter)
    foreach (Enum item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Tables.Controllers.FilterProperties)))
    {
        if (item.Equals(Tables.Controllers.FilterProperties.None))
        {
            continue;
        }
        <div>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="@((int)(object)item)" checked=@Model.Filter.HasFlag(item) />
                <span>@item</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    }
    <span id="filtererror" class="field-validation-error" hidden >Please select at least one property to search</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}

<table>
    ....
</table>
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Resolutions, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, Keyword = Model.Keyword, Filter = (int)Model.Filter }))
```

And then use javascript to andles the forms `.submit()` event to update the hidden input value for `Filter` (note I have also assumed that you want at least one checkbox selected if the value of `Keyword` is not `null`)

```
<script>
    var checkboxes = $('input:checkbox');
    var keyword = $('#Keyword');
    $('form').submit(function () {
        var filter = 0;
        // validate at least one checkbox must be checked if Keyword has a value
        if (keyword.val() && checkboxes.filter(':checked').length == 0) {
            $('#filtererror').show();
            return false;
        }
        $.each(checkboxes, function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                filter += Number($(this).val());
            }
            // disable checkboxes to prevent their value being added to the query string
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        })
        $('#Filter').val(filter);
    })

    checkboxes.click(function () {
        if (keyword.val() && checkboxes.filter(':checked').length == 0) {
            $('#filtererror').show();
        } else {
            $('#filtererror').hide();
        }
    })
</script>
```

Your URL (based on `ResolutionYear` and `ResolutionText` being checked) will now be

`.../Index?Keyword=someText&Filter=5`

instead of

`.../Index?Keyword=someText&IsResYearChecked=true&IsResYearChecked=false&IsResNumChecked=false&IsResTextChecked=true&IsResTextChecked=false`